# Passing integer array to method that uses a generic array of elements?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class

```
public class TestAlgorithm<E extends Comparable<? super E>> 
{
    public void testing(E[] array)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<= array.length; i++)
        {
            ... // processing code (not important here)
        }
    }
}
```

in my main application class class I have this...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int [] test = {3,7,8,5,2,1,9,5,4};
    TestAlgorithm<Integer> myAlgo = new TestAlgorithm<Integer>();

    myAlgo.testing(test);
}
```

Which to me - looks like it makes sense - but I get the following error when I try to run it...

> The method testing(Integer[]) in the type TestAlgorithm is not applicable for the arguments (int[]) app.java /TestApp/src/Application line 10 Java Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `myAlgo` as `Integer` type, but you are calling a vector of `int`. Use an `Integer` vector:

```
Integer[] test = {3,7,8,5,2,1,9,5,4};
```

Comment: I feel like such an idiot. Thanks!!!!!!